# Почему в ReactJS не происходит рендеринг компонента при history.push?

Tags: reactjs

Почему не происходит рендеринг компонента Login после того, как был запушин новый URL /user/login при помощи history.push? А вот при явном запросе URL /user/login - компонент Login рендериться как нужно.

```
import './../bootstrap'

import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom'
import {withRouter} from "react-router-dom"

import Header from './Header'

import Login from './Login'

import Footer from './Footer'

class App extends Component {

    componentWillMount() {

        if ( ! this.props.auth ) {

            this.props.history.push( '/user/login' )

        }

    }

    render() {

        return (

            <div>
                <Header />
                <Switch>
                    <Route path='/user/login' component={Login}/>
                </Switch>
                <Footer />
            </div>

        )

    }

}

const mapStateToProps = state => {

    return {

        auth: state.auth

    }

}

export default connect( mapStateToProps )( withRouter( App ) )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все заработало после того как я поменял экспорт App

Вариант, который был и НЕ работал:

```
export default connect( mapStateToProps )( withRouter( App ) )
```

Вариант, который заставил всё работать так, как нужно:

```
export default withRouter( connect( mapStateToProps )( App ) )
```

Видимо суть заключается в том, что withRouter это функция высшего порядка и в данном случае ее надо применять уже к результату функции connect.